# Argument labels '(UUIDString)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uuid

I converted my code to swift 3. And I got below error:

> Argument labels '(UUIDString)' do not match any available overloads

```
    locationManager.delegate = self
    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(UUIDString: "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"), identifier: "ru.techmas.techbeacon")
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

Anyone know about this error? (My Xcode version is 8.2)

Comment: A hint for such cases: ⌘-click on the class symbol or type ⇧⌘0 (zero), type the class name (UUID) in the search field and look up the syntax in the header file / documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializer of `UUID` is changed to [`init?(uuidString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/uuid/1779760-init) so change your parameter label to `uuidString` and it is return optional `UUID?` instance so you need wrapped the optional instance.

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0")!, identifier: "ru.techmas.techbeacon")
```

You can also optionally unwrapped optional using `if let` instead of force wrapping.

```
if let uuidStr = UUID(uuidString: "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0") {
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuidStr, identifier: "ru.techmas.techbeacon")
}
```

Comment: If it is working now please accept my answer, if you don't know how to accept answer check this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346600